# Do I need to install libcurl source package to use it for development?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, curl

I am working on a project that I used to use in a Windows environment. I recently migrated to KUbuntu and installed everything I needed (Qt, QtCreator and libcurl).

However, after installing libcurl, I see that libcurl doesn't come with header files that I need! I checked that this was not the case using

```
$ dpkg-query -L libcurl3
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libcurl3/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcurl3
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.3.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.3
```

So, will I need to install libcurl sources in order to get back to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header files are usually provided by `-dev` packages, in this case that would be `libcurl3-dev`, which is a virtual package now provided by [`libcurl4-ssl-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libcurl4-openssl-dev/filelist), which looks like it has header files. So install `libcurl3-dev`.

Comment: So that's what I missed... Thank you for your answer!